# mySQL query,what is wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've been asked to create a query for a database, the query is to create:
    A list of employees showing FirstName, LastName, Email, and Grade (textual title) where they have a skill containing the word ‘video’ (one entry per employee only even if employees have multiple video skills)

So far I've done this:

```
SELECT Employee.FirstName, Employee.LastName, Employee.Email, Grade.Title,
FROM Employee INNER JOIN
     Grade
     ON Grade.GradeID = Employee.GradeID INNER JOIN
     EmployeeSkill
     ON EmployeeSkill.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID INNER JOIN
     Skill
     ON Skill.SkillID = EmployeeSkill.SkillID
WHERE Skill.Title LIKE "%video%"
```

However I keep getting a 1064 error and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong please help.

Comment: Is this for an assignment? It's the kind of task given to students.

Comment: Yes I'm a first year student at UNI, and doing SQL for the first time

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma in the SELECT section of your query

```
    SELECT Employee.FirstName,
           Employee.LastName,
           Employee.Email,
           Grade.Title, -- Remove the comma here 
      FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Grade
        ON Grade.GradeID = Employee.GradeID
INNER JOIN EmployeeSkill 
        ON EmployeeSkill.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID 
INNER JOIN Skill 
        ON Skill.SkillID = EmployeeSkill.SkillID
     WHERE Skill.Title LIKE "%video%"
```